# PhpStorm: model property and DB column with the same name cause error highlight problems

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

Using newest version of PhpStorm with Laravel plugin and baryvdh ide-helper.

I have an eloquent model where I am trying to access column named `model` in my DB.

```
$table->model;
```

but `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` have property:

```
protected $model;
```

Due to that my PhpStorm highlight my `$table->model` line because it thinks that I am trying to call protected property instead of DB column.

Is there any possibility of fixing that or just ignoring this line, suppression mechanism build in to PhpStorm do not help?..

No options under alt+enter (looks like cannot ignore errors), also cannot change table column name. So far accessor is the only way, or turning off ide helper.

Comment: alt+enter and see ignore this inspection...

Comment: For some reason it feels nice to see a question that is about some annoying highlighting in an IDE. I guess many people would be thankful if this was the worst problem in their project. Or at least bad enough to ask SO about it. Oh well.

Comment: If it would be me ... I would simply rename the DB field (if I could, of course) .. or access it using different name (e.g. `modelName`) and then have [accessor/mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to access real field.